# How to check every data type from input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

Simple, I want to check the data type like `string, integer or *any other type*` which is input. We don't know the type and if it's a number I need to **get its absolute value**. However, if it's another type, I have other actions for each data type. For example, if it's a string print string or if it's a float print float like that. How can I solve this problem in a simple way?

Before asking this question, I've tried:

```py
def mainDataFunc():
    x = input("Anything: ")
    try:
        if type(abs(x)) is int:
            print("This is integer.")
        elif type(abs(x)) is float:
            print("This is float.")
        elif type(x) is str:
            print("This is string.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Type is not valid.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```py
user_input = input("Enter something ")

try:
    val = int(user_input)
    print("Input is an integer")
except ValueError:
    try:
        val = float(user_input)
        print("Input is a float")
    except ValueError:
        print("It's a string")
```